# Why won't the rendered image be my current active camera view?

Tags: rendering

I move the camera to the position I want and set it by using 'ctrl + alt + NUMPAD 0' and when I press 'NUMPAD 0' to see what the camera is looking the at the rendered image is different to the view of the camera.

Comment: Do you have multiple cameras?

Answer (score 2):

Happened to me once.. it’s possible your camera has key frames and is set to rotate away from your view port at the start of the animation.. there.. whatever view you set your camera..  render doesn’t see it.. so you just have to delete the camera and insert a fresh one.

Answer (score 1):

You might have a different camera, or object set as active camera.

To find the active camera go to the scene tab in the properties window. The active camera can be selected there.

[image]

Or you can set the active camera (or object as camera) in the 3D viewport.

Select a camera (or object) and make it an **Active Camera**

[image]

The shortcut is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad 0</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You should check if blender actually gets your keypress. Some OSes use that keycombo . If you press it you should see the camera outline appear in the 3d viewport.

If that doesn't happen you need to configure your OS to not use that key combo. Alternatively you can use view->align view->align active camera to view from the 3d viewport view menu.